# Creating a custom JSON API for Domino data with authentication

Tags: json, api, xpages

I need to expose custom domino data as json through an url/endpoint, 
I am creating an xAgent, xe:jsonRpcService or xe:restService that will expose the json

Applications from the internet/intranet will consume this data but I need them to authenticate.

How should I setup my Domino server to handle this Authentication and what kind of requests do the clients need to do to get the data as authenticated user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "basic authentication" for your API endpoint. If you have en existing internet site with session authentication, you can override that for your API endpoint by adding an "Override Session Authentication" web site rule for the API URLs. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: and when using basic authentication the username/pw is sent in the request header, right?